# Is it possible to prevent tensorflow keras progress bar from flooding IDLE shell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-idle

When using tensorflow.keras in the default python editor IDLE shell, any time a function shows a progress bar such as in keras.datasets.imdb.load_data() the progress bar floods the editor and the function takes forever. Is there a fix or do I need to find another editor?

(i'm currently working through the TensorFlow tutorials but prefer to do them in an interactive terminal)

Comment: Oh and I'm in Windows10 64 bit using Python 3.6.7

Comment: Try using an IDE like Pycharm

Comment: have shifted to using the IPython shell which doesn't experience the bug/feature